# Why does Rust stop detecting dead structs if they implement/derive some trait?

Tags: rust

Under normal circumstances, Rust warns if a struct is dead by generating a warning like:

```
struct `Foo` is never constructed
```

This is nice to detect unused types that can be removed.

However, I noticed that the compiler stops warning about dead structs as soon as they implement or derive some trait. For instance, for a source file consisting purely of:

```rust
struct DeadStruct1;

#[derive(Clone)]
struct DeadStruct2;
```

The compiler will only detect that `DeadStruct1` is unused, but not `DeadStruct2`, which is obviously not used in this program either (example on [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8c25c3ce9e9785951e0a10cd7abed0ad)):

```
warning: struct `DeadStruct1` is never constructed
 --> src/lib.rs:1:8
  |
1 | struct DeadStruct1;
  |        ^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
  = note: `#[warn(dead_code)]` on by default
```

I'm wondering why this lint depends on whether or not a struct implements a trait?

Comment: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57613 and https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/47851

Comment: @FZs "it's a known bug" is an answer and belongs in the text box one down from the questions comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is because of a known bug, it is discussed [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/57613) and [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/47851).

But... it's weird.

I tested the January 1st builds of each year between 2018 and 2023, and the problem got *worse* over time.

- The problem you're mentioning (with `#[derive(Clone)]`, and also for `PartialEq`, `Default`; but not for `Debug` and `Hash`, and also not if the trait was manually implemented) had already been there in `2018-01-01`. But at that point, only derived implementations caused it, manual implementations still had the warning.
- In `2019-01-01`, nothing seems to have changed.
- But then, by `2020-01-01`, some other cases stopped producing the warning too. This code demonstrates the behavior (from [this post](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/47851#issuecomment-629852474), also in the discussion linked above):

  ```
  struct Foo;

  // Does not prevent the warning
  trait Bar0 {}
  impl Bar0 for Foo {}

  // Does not prevent the warning
  trait Bar1 { fn dummy(); }
  impl Bar1 for Foo { fn dummy () {} }

  // Prevents the warning
  trait Bar2 { fn dummy(&self); }
  impl Bar2 for Foo { fn dummy (&self) {} }

  // Prevents the warning
  trait Bar3 { fn dummy() -> Self; }
  impl Bar3 for Foo { fn dummy () -> Self { todo!() } }

  // Prevents the warning
  trait Bar4 { type Dummy; }
  impl Bar4 for Foo { type Dummy = Self; }

  // Prevents the warning
  trait Bar5 { const DUMMY: Self; }
  impl Bar5 for Foo { const DUMMY: Self = Self; }
  ```
- And, as we arrive to `2021-01-01`, now *any* (non-blanket) trait implementation silences the warning, no matter if derived or manual, mentions `Self` or not!

  And this seems to be the behavior we have to this day.

Comment: Note that I ran into it when explicitly implementing the `Iterator` trait for a struct, so that seems affected as well. EDIT: Ah it's rather _any_ trait currently...